# How to fix this compile error for Xdebug on Homestead

Tags: xdebug, homestead

I cannot install Xdebug on Homestead because I get some sort of compile error.

I am following the Xdebug Wizard (https://xdebug.org/wizard) and when I input the `./configure` command I get this error:

> configure: error: in /home/vagrant/code/xdebug-2.7.2:
>   configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
>   If you meant to cross compile, use '--host'.
>   See 'config.log' for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This points at that you don't have a C compiler installed at all. You will have better luck after installing the php-dev package first, which should pull in the compilers that PHP extensions will need.

Comment: I get this when installing (the ./configure error remains the same):

php-dev is already the newest version (2:7.3+69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: I found this meanwhile pecl install xdebug. It's much easier for a newbie like me than compiling so I'm going with that. Choosing as best answer since you're probably right but I don't have the time right now to research how to point to php-dev on linux.